# Angular 4 AOT giving "could not resolve" error

Tags: angular, angular2-aot

I have two declaration files which are loadmethods.d.ts and staticUrl.d.ts. I used these declaration files to include some jquery functions into my angular application. It's working fine with JIT, but want to move to AOT.But I'm getting following error after run this command **node_modules/.bin/rollup -p tsconfig-aot.json**

> [!] Error: Could not resolve '../Declaration/loadMethods' from App\Services\api.service.js
>   Error: Could not resolve '../Declaration/loadMethods' from App\Services\api.service.js
>       at error (E:\Tests\AOT TEST\Versla.Admin\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:185:14)
>       at then.resolvedId (E:\Tests\AOT TEST\Versla.Admin\node_modules\rollup\dist\rollup.js:10062:8)

I have referenced the declaration file and imported it as follows in app.service.ts file,
[image]

**tsconfig-aot.json** file as follows.

```
{
"compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "typeRoots": [
        "./node_modules/@types/"
    ]
},

"files": [
    "App/app.module.ts",
    "App/main.ts"
],

"angularCompilerOptions": {
    "genDir": "aot",
    "skipMetadataEmit": true
}
```

}

Coudn't find any solution, any sugestions to avoid this?

Comment: Seem like rollup is trying to include the declaration files but declaration files compile to nothing in javascript, if you remove the imports are you still able to compile with out type error? If not try adding the  declaration files to the tsconfig files: [] or add ../declaration to the typeRoots: []

Comment: @WilliamLohan once remove the import lines can't compile. at that stage it will gives an error when use this command "node_modules/.bin/ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json".

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: Something like this Error at E:/Tests/AOT TEST/Versla.Admin/App/Components/Admin/booking.component.ts:195:9: Cannot find name 'ConfigDatePicker'.

Comment: try adding the declaration files to the tsconfig files: [] or add ../declaration to the typeRoots: []

Comment: @WilliamLohan Thanks mate, that work like a charm. but another error comes, I think something related to RXJS. error as follows, do you have any idea? 

[!] Error: 'Subject' is not exported by node_modules\rxjs\Subject.js
https://github.com/rollup/rollup/wiki/Troubleshooting#name-is-not-exported-by-module
node_modules\@angular\core\@angular\core.es5.js (10:9)
 8: import { merge } from 'rxjs/observable/merge';
 9: import { share } from 'rxjs/operator/share';
10: import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157859/discussion-between-harshana-narangoda-and-william-lohan).